# Selenium. Cannot click on element?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I get the following error when trying to click on a radioButton:
**Cannot click on element**.
My code is:

```
public static IWebDriver WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();    
var radioButton = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='" + 
elementName + "' and @value='" + value + "']"));
radioButton.Click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the value and elementName?

Try to validate your XPath with one of the many Firefox XPath extensions.

Comment: i have : `<input type="radio" name="x" value="Y"><input type="radio" name="x" value="Z">` value is y,z and elementName is x <br />

Comment: I found a workaround is to use javascript:`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('myradiobutton1').click()");` [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2439)

Comment: Then try to use the By.id for myradionbutton1, without the need for the javascript call overhead.